# display icon on mouse hover in Accordion via JavaScript (EventHandler)

Tags: javascript, events, getelementsbyclassname

**EDIT UPDATE:** *Deleted original question and revising to make easier to read.*

OK,so I figured it out! Or kinda! Here's the JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/reflexez/d7yvym8q/2/

```
var test = document.getElementById("what");
var accordionList = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
var j;

for(i=0; i < accordionList.length; i++) {
  accordionList[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {

//document.getElementById("accordion-icon").style.display = "block";
var addIcon = this.firstChild.nextElementSibling;
addIcon.style.display = "block"
console.log(addIcon);
  });
}


for(j=0; j < accordionList.length; j++) {
  accordionList[j].addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {

    //document.getElementById("accordion-icon").style.display = "none";
    var removeIcon = this.firstChild.nextElementSibling;
    removeIcon.style.display = "none"
    console.log(removeIcon);
  });
}
```

my site:
http://alpizano.com

I'm a Comp. Engineering student and have taken up to Data Structures in Java but I never formally learned JavaScript (teaching myself now) so that's why something as trivial as this was giving me issues.

I STILL have a question though for the future if you guys could help me out. Is the ONLY way to get information out of the "current" item being accessed by the for loop, that is,  the arrayList[i] item,instead of firstChild, parentNode, nextElementSibling etc...?

These functions seem really sloppy to me coming from Java. I know I've done LinkedLists and similiar stuff with nodes and LinkedList.getLink stuff to the the contents of the next item in the list, but if the HTML is really sloppy, like in my case, I had multiple DIVs, and the  tag immediately after the DIV, then a

tag, then another DIV, it seems so convulted.

I figured there was a way to just do like accordionList[i].getElementById("the ID of the tag you want goes here, like in my case the  tag because I want to change it from display: none to block");

obviously it didn't work that way and I had to use firstChild.nextElementSibling but I am still wondering. And yes, I am currently reading the JS script book written by Duckett which I don't find that good actually.

Honestly, I see why pro JS programmers debug in chrome and console.log their outputs, because, the only reason I figured it out was that I was typing random code and was console.log miscellanous variables to and checking them in chrome, and I did .firstChild and it came up NULL, but then in chrome, it said the .nextElementSibling to that was the  tag I needed to manipulate.

Either way, I hope this helps other people and I hope I provided research & intent on my part to code this that you guys give me a thumbs up :D

Comment: nice it worked out for you :)
as I already mentioned in my previous answer - when you remove the duplicate IDs and mark the icon instead via a class, you can get rid of `firstChild.nextElementSibling;` --> that always depends on your structure and fails when additional elements are inserted inbetween.
instead access it via a selector (the class) from the current element
`this.getElementsByClassName('accordion-icon')[0]`

Comment: Ah, that's exactly what I wanted to know!, doing the child/next element stuff seemed to elementary and fine for simpler HTML but convoluted if your HTML had multiple nodes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First - for the next question, please provide a full "working" code example - your javascript code differ from your posted html (e.g. you are accessing the id `accordion-icon` which is not available in your html. But with the link to your website i got a good overall view :)

The main problem is - you have more than one element with the id `accordion-icon` - don't do that, IDs should be unique
--> so I removed the id and add it instead as a additonal class to the icon (see snipped below)

The second thing is you want only the corresponding icon to be visible. In your event listener callback function you can access `event.target` which points to the element triggering the event listener (e.g. the current `div.accordion`). From this element you search for the next icon and only show/hide this one. (see snipped below)

And the last thing - you need to hide the icons at the beginning - do it via js (like in my example) or directly in the html on each icon

```js
var test = document.getElementById("what");
var accordionList = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
var j;

//hide all icons first (or instead hide it directly via style in html)
var iconsList = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-icon");
for(i=0; i < iconsList.length; i++){
  iconsList[i].style.display = "none";
}


for(i=0; i < accordionList.length; i++) {
  accordionList[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
    //only set style for the next icon (inside current accordion)
    event.target.getElementsByClassName('accordion-icon')[0].style.display = "block";
  });
}


for(j=0; j < accordionList.length; j++) {
  accordionList[j].addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event) {
    event.target.getElementsByClassName('accordion-icon')[0].style.display = "none";
  });
}
```

```css
.panel {margin-bottom:30px;}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
    <i class="accordion-icon fas fa-arrow-down">icon1</i>
    Title of accordion box goes here, after arrow icon.
</div>        
<div class="panel">
    Text inside accordion goes here.
</div>

<div class="accordion">
    <i class="accordion-icon fas fa-arrow-down">icon2</i>
    Title of accordion box goes here, after arrow icon.
</div>        
<div class="panel">
    Text inside accordion goes here.
</div>

<div class="accordion">
    <i class="accordion-icon fas fa-arrow-down">icon3</i>
    Title of accordion box goes here, after arrow icon.
</div>        
<div class="panel">
    Text inside accordion goes here.
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my question and included the JSfiddle. Thank you for taking the time to respond. Would you know how to add a transistion delay of 0.4s for the icon to appear? Would I have to do this in the Javascript or CSS?